# Docker: Finding the URI for Redis image to reference in ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I am using Redis locally for a caching service in my Docker project. For my other services, I built the images, and pushed them to ECR. The Redis service is the standard service.

```
services:

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2
```

**Question**
How do you find the URI for a standard image like this to reference in the container to my Task Definition?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the ECS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definitions) you should be able to use “short” names for images on Docker Hub: try just typing in `redis:3.2` there and see if it works.

If all of the parts (server hostname, namespace, image name) are really required, `docker.io/library/redis:3.2` is the exact same image, just with the typical Docker Hub defaults filled in.